# Set Background - Picture in Framelayout

Tags: android, background, image

Perhaps very simple, but not for me ;)

How do i change the Picture of a Framelayout in my sourcecode?

My first intention was:

```
mBackgroundDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.picture);
main.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackgroundDrawable);
```

but there i only can add pictures from my "RES/DRAWABLE-HDPI" folder.
I want to use my SD-Card as the destinated source.

Whats the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/test2.png");
image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
BitmapDrawable dr=new BitmapDrawable(bMap);
```

Comment: But how do i transfer this to a Drawable? I can only use setBackgroundDrawable or setBackgroundResource.

Comment: try this:     BitmapDrawable dr=new BitmapDrawable(bMap);

Comment: I think you did't read the exact question. Can you elaborate your answer that how "Set Background - Picture in Framelayout".. you have made the Bitmap but how to set in the framelayout?

Comment: Yes, same problem here. Perhaps it helped but the answer is not complete and wouldn´t help others.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert your `Bitmap` to a `BitmapDrawable` before able to set it as a background.

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.file.absolutePath)
frameLayout.background = BitmapDrawable(context.resources, bitmap)
```